# How to find the total number of operations in a MongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, performance, replication

I wanted to get the total number of operations (CRUD) hitting on my MongoDB cluster (Replicaset) for a single day.
There is `slowms:100` hence extraction from the log wont be a solution.

is there any way we can get this?

Comment: You can use `db.serverStatus().opcounters`  _and / or_ `db.serverStatus().metrics.document` to get the CRUD operation counts. But, you may have to manually get the info at different hours of a day to calculate the numbers during that period.